# Using present perfect simple in a real world situation

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, tense, present-perfect, grammaticality-in-context

I do not know when I have to use the present perfect simple (and others tenses in **perfect** form). I normally use: present simple, present continuous, past simple, past continuous, future, ... for write/speak. I hardly ever use tenses in **perfect** form.

So I imagined a real world situation for work with present perfect simple. I will work with these present perfect simple grammar rules:

> **Experiences**
>
> We use the present perfect simple to talk about our experiences up to now. The time of the experiences is not important:
>
> **Recent completed events**
>
> We use the present perfect simple to talk about a finished event or state in the very recent past. We do not give a specific time. We often use words like just or recently for events taking place a very short time before now:
>
> **Past events, present results**
>
> We use the present perfect simple when a single past action has a connection with the present:
>
> Source: [Present perfect simple](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/gramatica/gramatica-britanica/present-perfect-simple-i-have-worked?q=Present%20perfect%20simple%3A%20form)

(**Situation**: I work at GlobalTech company as software developer in the development department. In this conversation workmates and me discuss about a meeting between our development department's leader and the company's boss. NOTE: Developer department's leader is Javi and Company's boss is Manuel)

> **Me:** (I am working in a project...) Oh my God, this problem again, **I have fixed** this problem many times... This is worse than a nightmare.
>
> **Javi:** (He comes to our department after a meeting with Manuel...) Listen! **I have talked** with Manuel about the project which we are working with... **We have decided** that the deadline will be the next week, ok.
>
> **Javi:** I will come in a moment, see you now.
>
> (a few days later...)
>
> **Workmates:** We can not more, we are working so hard, we will not achieve to finish the project for the next week. We do not understand why **they have decided** a project's deadline without our opinion. We have to talk with Javi.
>
> **Me:** Yes, we MUST.

I will explain which present perfect simple's grammar rules I used for each one:

**I have fixed** : "Experiences". I got a problem in that moment and I said that I had the same problem many times before.

**I have talked** AND **We have decided** : "Recent completed events". He is talking about a finished event (a meeting) in the very recent past.

**they have decided** : "Past events, present results". Because both leaders' decision (some days ago) was causing burnout over us (in the present).

So I ask you: When I used the present perfect simple, **Do you see them as a good choice in that conversation?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds fine to me. In some cases, using present perfect as you did may sound a bit more formal than using past simple even, which is quite desireable in such a work environment.

> I have fixed this problem many times

I'd understand this as you've done it many times before already and may do it more in the future.

> I have talked ...
>   We have decided ...

Indeed, I would understand that you **just** did those actions very recently, likely right before the discussion.

> They have decided ...

This is a pretty common phrase to say and hear. "I've decided to ..." isn't uncommon to hear.